# Write row to a CSV file without it adding quotation marks

Tags: python

My first problem:

```
writer.writerow(['Name,' 'Street,,' 'Address,,,'])
```

The above example returns "Name,Street,,Address,,,"

I need it to return Name,Street,,Address,,, without the quotation marks.

What should I do?

Comment: Quotes aren't a bad thing in CSV files.  If your field has a comma in it, quotes are the only thing telling you that it isn't a delimiter.

Comment: To make a list of strings, the commas need to be between the strings, not inside them. (And don't try to manually add literal commas to the strings to make more columns, that's not going to work.)

Comment: also I dont think you can call writerow on the Class but rather an instance ... just in case you have `from  csv import writer` above this line ... I suspect you are getting some syntax errors if this is really your code ...

Answer (score 14):

Ignacio's answer is absolutely right and is the one you want to use in practice.

But if you want to instruct csv to never use quotes, which is what the question seems to be literally asking, you can set the dialect paramater for quoting to csv.QUOTE_none.  It would look like:

```
    theWriter = csv.writer(open('thefile.csv', 'wb'), 
delimeter = ',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Also, if you really want to micromanage what goes intot he file, you can skip the csv library and just write strings to the file.

Answer (score 8):

Stop putting commas in your values.

```
writer.writerow(['Name', '', 'Street', '', '', 'Address', '', '', ''])
```

Comment: I think it should be `writer.writerow(['Name', 'Street', '', 'Address', '', ''])`, and in might be worthwhile mentioning _why_.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open("lame.csv","w") as f:
      w = csv.writer(f)
      w.writerow(["frank","tom","mike","paul"])
```

does not put quotes in the file....

If you are seeing a string in python they always have quotes in the repr ... you can use print to not show the quotes that wrap a python string ...

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to this and tried it this way, but it still puts quotes around each line