# How to split a large file into chunks using python

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv 

divisor = 1000000 

outfileno = 1 
outfile = None 

with open('o77069882.txt', 'r') as infile: 

    infile_iter = csv.reader(infile) 
    header = next(infile_iter) 
    for index, row in enumerate(infile_iter): 
        if index % divisor == 0: 
            if outfile is not None: 
                outfile.close() 
            outfilename = 'big-{}.csv'.format(outfileno) 
            outfile = open(outfilename, 'w') 
            outfileno += 1 
            writer = csv.writer(outfile) 
            writer.writerow(header) 
        writer.writerow(row) 
    # Don't forget to close the last file 
    if outfile is not None: 
        outfile.close()
```

I am using this above code to divide my file into chunks of size 100000, it does the job but each row in the first file is getting enclosed by quotes( " ") as for example "abc, dfg, ghj, kil" . The second and third file created are not having this problem, can anyone help me modify my code to get rid of the above error.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804438/write-row-to-a-csv-file-without-it-adding-quotation-marks)

Comment: can you post a sample of the input file?